# preg_replace with variable input

Tags: php, regex

I'm quite new to this, and have borrowed some code from another post I found, I don't know if what I am trying to do is the right or the best way, its just how I am "getting" it to work..

This is the code

```
<?php
$yn = $_POST['YN'];
echo $yn;
$fl='config.php'; 
        /*read operation ->*/ $tmp = fopen($fl, "r");   $content=fread($tmp,filesize($fl)); fclose($tmp);

// here goes your update
$content = preg_replace('/\$yourname = \"(.*?)\";/', '$yourname = ""$YN"";', $content);


        /*write operation ->*/ $tmp =fopen($fl, "w");    fwrite($tmp, $content);    fclose($tmp);
?>
```

I am trying to update a config file entry that matches $yourname with the POST result, I can echo $yn and it contains the correct value, but I can't get the variable to work in the regex replace,

```
$content = preg_replace('/\$yourname = \"(.*?)\";/', '$yourname = ""$yn"";', $content);
```

so if $yn = karl then im trying to update $yourname = "" in the file to $yourname = "karl"

but I can't get it to work, the closest I get is it updating the file with the variable as text, ie $yourname = "$yn".

hope someone can help

Comment: If you remove the double " around $yn so that you only have "$yn" does it work then?

Comment: Well first off the singe `'` cant be used for variable interpolation in php.  Meaning it's taken literally, and not as the value.  In order for the variable value to be present you must use either `"` double quote or concatenation `'words'.$foo`

Comment: Variables such as `$YN` won't interpolate in single quotes (regardless of the additional double quoting mishap within). -- And this is perhaps irrelevant and hopefully not a security-critical aspect, but for proper encoding of literal values for PHP context use [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216)

Comment: I would also suggest using `preg_quote($var)` in any regx to properly escape special characters.  With a name you might be ok, but things like `.` or `[` have special meaning in regx's

Comment: If I remove the double " it updates the file with $yn not the variable value

Comment: same thing the `'` quotes around the replacement as I stated before, single quote doesn't replace the variable with its value, its literal text

Comment: @user3768497 - I feel I need to mention to that `$YN` is not the same as `$yn` -  as variables are case sensitive, I see both used in the post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest using a pattern like this

```
     preg_replace( '/'.preg_quote( $yourname ).'\s*=\s*\"[^\"]+\";/', $yourname.'="'.$yn.'";', $content);
```

..'\s*=\s*\"([^\"]+)\";

- preg_quote( $yourname ) - escaped variable input ( literal match )
- \s* - one or more spaces
- = - literal (=)
- \s* - one or more space
- \" - literal (")
- [^\"]+ - match any character not a (") greedy match as many times as possible.
- \" - literal (")
- ;  literal (;)

In this case ( because it uses double quotes ), it's (prudent?) better to use concatenation and save the headache of escaping it. No need to be `fancy` when simplicity will win the day.

Also be wary of mistakes like this `$yn` vs `$YN` in php variable names are case sensitive, without that knowledge it can be a major challenge to find the error, because to us humans it looks the same.  Of course it doesn't help that file names, class names, functions and methods are case insensitive ( on Windows ).  Really not sure if class and method names are case sensitive on linux, I try to avoid the issue and always use the same casing.

Seeing as it looks like the OP possibly wanted  `$yourname` ( literally ) I updated the regx

```
 preg_replace( '/\$yourname\s*=\s*\"[^\"]+\";/', '$yourname="'.$yn.'";', $content);
```

https://regex101.com/r/yM9cX9/1

Answer (score 0):

Using what you posted I managed to get it working, thank you so much :)

```
$content =   preg_replace( '/\$yourname = \"(.*?)\";/', '$yourname = "'.$yn.'";', $content);
```

Comment: oh, did you mean the literal `$yourname` or the value of it?

Comment: Yeah $yourname should have been $yourname and $yn the variable value, I managed to get what I wanted working, thank you so much for your help :)